# Prove two random variables are negatively correlated

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, correlation

Given a raw estimator

\begin{equation}
I=I(X>b)= \begin{cases}1, \text{ if } X > b\\ 0, \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}
\end{equation}

for some random variable $X$ and some constant $b$ in the range of the distribution of $X$.

I was trying to prove that $I$ and $-X$ are negatively correlated. Here is what I tried so far, and then I am stuck.

\begin{align}
& Cov(I,-X) = \mathbb E\{I(-X)\} - \mathbb E \{I\} \mathbb E \{-X\} \\
= & - \mathbb E\{IX\} + \mathbb E\{I\} \mathbb E\{X\} \\
= & - \big[ \mathbb E\{X|X>b\} \Pr (X > b) \big] + \mathbb E\{X\} \Pr(X > b) \\
= & \big[ \mathbb E\{X\} - \mathbb E\{X|X > b\} \big] \Pr(X > b).
\end{align}

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done.  The next step is to write
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X \mid X > b] \Pr[X > b] + \operatorname{E}[X \mid X \le b]\Pr[X \le b], \tag{1}$$
and then observe that
$$\operatorname{E}[X \mid X \le b] \le b. \tag{2}$$  So if we let $a = \operatorname{E}[X \mid X > b]$ and $p = \Pr[X > b]$,
$$\operatorname{Cov}[I, -X] \le (ap + b(1-p) - a)p = (-a(1-p) + b(1-p))p = (b-a)(1-p)p. \tag{3}$$
But for the same reason that $(2)$ is true, we also have
$$a = \operatorname{E}[X \mid X > b] > b. \tag{4}$$
Therefore, since $0 < p < 1$, and $a > b$, then
$$\operatorname{Cov}[I,-X] \le (b-a)(1-p)p < 0.$$

Comment: Thank you. I failed to realize E(X|X<=b)<=b, and your explanation is so clear.